# graph display problem

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, python

I have a problem with the end of my code. I would like to display the last two curves, the problem is that at the beginning the size of YY is 288 and then after the equality with diff, my size goes to 238. So when I display the curves I have exactly the same thing, which is normal. But I wish I could show the curve for a size of 288 and I do not understand why YY changed size after the tie ...

Here is the code:

```
options = pd.read_csv("/Users/***/Documents/***",sep =',',header = 0)



n=prices.settle_sp_price.size 
x=np.arange(0,n)

p1 =sp.polyfit(x, prices.settle_sp_price,3)
pp1 =np.polyval(p1, x)



diff = prices.settle_sp_price-pp1


Y=np.zeros(prices.settle_sp_price.size)

for i in range(1,prices.settle_sp_price.size):
 if Y[i] > .1*Y[i]:
  Y[i] = 0


Y=np.fft.fft(diff)
PP=np.fft.ifft(Y)
YY=[0]*(prices.settle_sp_price.size+50)
a=[0]*prices.settle_sp_price.size
b=[0]*prices.settle_sp_price.size

print('aa')
print(len(YY))
#=288

#interpolate the difference for 90days
for n in range(prices.settle_sp_price.size,prices.settle_sp_price.size+30):
    YY[n]=0
    for k in range(1,prices.settle_sp_price.size):
     a[k]=np.real(Y[k])
     b[k]=-np.imag(Y[k])
     omk=2*math.pi*(k-1)/prices.settle_sp_price.size 
     YY[n]=YY[n]+a[k]*math.cos(omk*(n-1))+b[k]*math.sin(omk*(n-1))

    YY[n]=-YY[n]/prices.settle_sp_price.size

print('bb')
print(len(YY))
#=288


YY = [c for c in diff]
print('cc')
print(len(YY))
#=238



plt.figure()


plt.plot(x,prices.settle_sp_price,'b');
plt.plot(x,tot,'r')
plt.hold()

plt.xlabel('time(days)')
plt.ylabel(' price')
plt.title('Stock price. Actual vs. theoretical 505 days')
```

Comment: This is not a signal processing, but a programming question (how to set the displayed range of numbers using pyplot). It is hence off-topic here, but could be asked on StackOverflow.com

Comment: however, `plt.xlim`.

Comment: sorry I did not pay attention ... I did not understand your plt.xlim

Comment: `pyplot.xlim` is the function whose documentation you should be reading.